# Why change class attribute for the HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Following HTML is from a [page](https://www.google.com/about/company/facts/management/) at Google's corporate site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="google" lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
(function(H){H.className=H.className.replace(/\bgoogle\b/,'google-js')})(document.documentElement)
    </script>
...
```

I understand what it does, but do not understand the reason behind it.  Why would you want to change the class attribute as above?  (I am new to web development.)

Comment: It might be simply for aesthetic purposes to show the user/developer inspecting the DOM that JavaScript is enabled because if it not than `<html>` won't have class `google-js`

Comment: That's probably for checking JS availability. Different styles when JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: @Vohuman May I ask you to please post your comment in an expanded form as an answer?

Comment: @self Thank you.  BTW, when I inspect the page using Developer tools in Chrome, I see this: `html class="google-js clickberry-extension clickberry-extension-standalone"` - so, based on your comment, what is visible in Developer tools is the actual, processed page, after all replacements have been applied, rather than the static page source.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Developer tools show you the actual state of the page DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in accessibility, there are some screenreaders (a minority now) that cannot handle javascript. 
These same screenreaders also use their own css to help users with handicap to handle better the website.
 in some case, you may want to add some styles or functionality, that is not "accessible".

An example of an Accessibility case, you have a style that is applied only if your javascript can create dynamically a specific DOM, well, no-js, means that you dont have your new DOM, and then, dont need to add this specific class to apply the new style. 
Hope it's more clear.